# PHP For Loop Working

Tags: php

I have few lines of code that I think will work normally in any language. But this is not working in PHP. In my case I want to print numbers in ascending order. The code I have written is below:

```
$i = 0;
printf("<p>Numbers in Ascending Order : ");
for (;++i <= 10;) {
    printf("%3d", $i);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

But I get a syntax error which is given below:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<=' (T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL),
>   expecting

Why is PHP displaying an error message like this ?

Comment: see manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Mayhaps if you added a `$` in front of the `++i` like so: `++$i`.

Comment: It's `++$i`, not `++i`.

Comment: Check demo of your code https://eval.in/567191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `$` in for loop variable

it should be:

```
$i = 0;
printf("<p>Numbers in Ascending Order : ");
for (;++$i <= 10;) {
        ^
    printf("%3d", $i);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: yes perfect. I have added same in comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

In php all variable names start with `$` character. On your loop there is plain `i`. Add `$` sign and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `$` in your variable.Replace `++i` with `++$i`.It should be like this:

```
$i = 0;
printf("<p>Numbers in Ascending Order : ");
for (;++$i <= 10;) {
    printf("%3d", $i);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` sign is missing from the `i` variable in the loop. In PHP the `$` sign goes everywhere not just in variable decleration

```
    $i = 0;
    printf("<p>Numbers in Ascending Order : ");
    for (;++$i <= 10;) {
       printf("%3d", $i);
       printf("\n\n");
    }
```